# How to control between two event in LongListSelector?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have create WP8 app.  I have created longlistselector.  I put button in longlistselector.  I have write button event.  It is working fine.  But i want to  write selection event also on that control.   Here i have problem.  First,when click button inside listselector, selection event is called.

Two column have data, another column have button.  When click the data, no problem even if the selection event is called.  When click the button, only button event need to called not selection event.

If button is part of list, how will avoid SelectionChanged event only on button.

Any one assist me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In this cae try adding LongListSelector Tap/SelectionChanges event dynamically.means in OnNavigatedTo just add it and in Button Tap.Click remove it.Thats it.

Suppose it is Tap of list then do like this in button click:

```
list.Tap -= list_Tap;//list_Tap is Tap event handler
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: If you s succeed.Don't forget to accept my answer.Cheers.

Comment: Are you able to do that? :)

Comment: Actually, i need to call selection event in particular scenario. E.g.  I have three columns 1. name 2. age 3. button for calculation in single row of longlistselector.  If i click name, selection changed event must be called.  If i click button of each row, button event only called.

Comment: If button is part of your list then SelectionChanged will be fired, anyways you can ignore it as I said above.